# Sencha Touch Last Accessed Pages

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I need an option to see the last accessed few pages in Sencha Touch application. I have many panels in my application and at run time I change the view-port item based on different conditions. I need a list of last accessed pages on a button click and from there I should be  able to select each pages with the old data on that page.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I know is not exactly what you are asking, but did you consider wrapping your app in a main navigationView?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But that will not work for me as my aim is to get a particular page directly on a click, not using back button

Comment: I know that, what I meant is that you can use the stack of views it mantains as items.

Comment: Thanks again, but my issue is I have different set of menus, which I cannot include inside one view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get it using [routes](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes) and adding actions or hashes into a localstore.

You could create an Ext.List with that store and change window.location on the ItemTap callback.

Take a look at the [history support guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/history_support).

hope it helps-